# Using vue, I want a component to be at the very top of the page, but only for a single view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Using the code below, the component SiteHead will appear on ALL pages, at the very top, above all other components but I only want this to happen for the HomeView.vue page.

I would like the component to be at the very top of the HomeView page, above the SiteNavigation component. Placing the SiteHead component into the HomeView.vue code would place this below SiteNavigation.

How would I go about this?

This is my App.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen font-Roboto bg-back-light dark:bg-back-dark">
    <SiteHead />
    <SiteNavigation />
    <RouterView />
    <SiteFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {RouterView} from "vue-router";
  import SiteNavigation from "./components/SiteNavigation.vue";
  import SiteFooter from "./components/SiteFooter.vue";
  import SiteHead from "./components/SiteHead.vue";
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

and this is my HomeView.vue code (pretty much empty at the moment though):

```
<script setup>
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <p class="text-white p-10">Home</p>
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: i don't understand your problem please be clear what you need where and when it needs to appear or disappear

Comment: Are you using vue3?

Comment: Yes, I am using vue3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this is by placing the `SiteHead` component inside the template of the `HomeView.vue` file, and not in the `App.vue` file.

HomeView.vue file:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <SiteHead />
    <p class="text-white p-10">Home</p>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
  import SiteHead from "./components/SiteHead.vue";
  export default {
    components: {
      SiteHead
    }
  }
</script>
```

### Solution 2

Alternatively you can conditionally render the `SiteHead` component in the `App.vue` template, using the `v-if` directive. To do this, you need to use a computed property to determine if the current route is the home page. So here is how your `App.vue` should look like:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen font-Roboto bg-back-light dark:bg-back-dark">
    <SiteHead v-if="isHomePage" />
    <SiteNavigation />
    <RouterView />
    <SiteFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import {RouterView, useRoute} from "vue-router";
import SiteNavigation from "./components/SiteNavigation.vue";
import SiteFooter from "./components/SiteFooter.vue";
import SiteHead from "./components/SiteHead.vue";

const Route = useRoute();

const isHomePage= computed(() => {
  return Route.path === '/'
})


</script>
```

Comment: I should have been more clear with this, I would like that component to be at the very top, above the SiteNavigation component

Answer (score 4):

You could make use of the `teleport` feature of Vue3:

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html#basic-usage

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen font-Roboto bg-back-light dark:bg-back-dark">
    <div id="site-head"></div>
    <SiteNavigation />
    <RouterView />
    <SiteFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {RouterView} from "vue-router";
  import SiteNavigation from "./components/SiteNavigation.vue";
  import SiteFooter from "./components/SiteFooter.vue";
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

`HomeView.vue`

```
<template>
  <main>
    <p class="text-white p-10">Home</p>
    <Teleport to="#site-head">
      <SiteHead />
    </Teleport>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
  import SiteHead from "./components/SiteHead.vue";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This also solved the issue! nice to learn a few more things :)